# React Router запомнить предыдущий url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Всем привет у меня есть такая вот проверка на авторизованность, если пользователь открывает страницу и он не авторизован то его редиректит на страницу авторизации

```
const CheckRoute = ({
  component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      const isLoggedIn = !!Cookies.get('token');
      return isLoggedIn ?
        (<Component {...props} />)
        :
        (<Redirect to={{pathname: '/login' }}/>);
    }
    }
  />
);

export default () => (
  <Switch>
    <CheckRoute path="/" exact component={Home}/>
    <CheckRoute path="/users" exact component={UserList}/>
    <CheckRoute path="/logout" exact component={LogOutRoute}/>
    <Route path="/login" render={props => {
      const isLoggedIn = !!Cookies.get('token');
      return !isLoggedIn ?
        (<LogIn/>)
        :
        (<Redirect to={{pathname: '/'}}/>);
    }}/>
    <Route path="/users/:id" exact component={UserDetail}/>
    <Route component={NotFound}/>
  </Switch>
);
```

Как сделать так, чтобы после авторизации он возвращался на страницу с которой пришел, т.е предыдущая куда он хотел попасть но его редиректнуло, как например через localstorage

Answer (score 2):

В самой простой реализации будет выглядеть следующим образом. Предположим у нас есть корневой компонент `App`, в него мы попадаем в первую очередь, объявим внутри `constructor` переменную в `state` и запомним наш `url` с коротого мы пришли:

```
this.state = {
  url: window.location.href,
}
```

Просто сохраним URL целиком в состоянии родительского компонента. При этом `Route` и `Redirect` не должны породить перезагрузку страницы, чтобы значение `url` не перезаписалось в состоянии компонента. Напишем здесь же метод, который будет вызываться, когда пользователь войдет:

```
afterLogIn() {
  document.location.assign(this.state.url);
}
```

Метод максимально простой, он загружает ресурс по URL, указанному в качестве параметра. Этот параментр мы достаем из стейта. Данный метод нужно передать в компоненту логина через `props` и вызвать после успешного входа пользователя. Чтобы редирект успешно отработал, должно быть полное соответсвие URL, так как у вас используется признак `exact` в рутах. Это своего рода маленький костылик (в любом случае нужно сохранить URL с которого мы пришли, чтобы потом заредиректить на него).

Полезные ссылки:

- [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location)
- [Location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)
- [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href)
- [`react-router` - How to get previous path?](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1066)
- [Detect previous path in react router?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39289862/5275890)

P.S.: данный подход проверил в своем React приложении и всё успешно работает.